# Unable to achieve aggregation using date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have JSON Data

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "Index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "supportdate": "20180631T000000Z",
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "Index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "supportdate": "20190622T000000Z",
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "Index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "supportdate": "20181231T000000Z",
            }
         }
]
```

Am trying to write aggregation query which will find records in particular "supportdate" range and categorise records as "Active and Expiring" buckets. Support date field has ISO date format(YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ).

As I have tried different date range queries, but no luck. As am new to elastic search database, bit struggling.

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Can you show your mapping and the query you're tried?